# I am trying to set up a table in an ORACLE database and am getting an invalid data type error when I try to run this command:

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE LIGNE DE COMMANDE (
  ligne_Commande_ID NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT ligne_commande_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  Quantité NUMBER (3) CONSTRAINT ligne_comm_qtt NOT NULL,
  Article_ID NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT ligneComm_article_fk REFERENCES article(article_id),
  Catégorie_ID NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT ligneComm_catégorie_fk REFERENCES catégorie(catégorie_id),
  Commande_ID NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT ligneComm_comm_fk REFERENCES commande(commande_id)) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: Table names must be enclosed in quotation marks if they contain spaces. I suggest naming the table `LIGNE_DE_COMMANDE` instead, i.e. no spaces.

Comment: Maybe `Quantité` also needs to be quoted: `"Quantité"`

Answer (score 0):

With `NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8` , it will work when you just wrap the column names(`QUANTITÉ` and `CATÉGORIE_ID`) and table name (`LIGNE DE COMMANDE`) in double-quotes(`"`).

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
  2  WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                                VALUE
---------------------------------------- ----------
NLS_CHARACTERSET                         AL32UTF8

SQL>

SQL> CREATE TABLE "LIGNE DE COMMANDE" (
  2      LIGNE_COMMANDE_ID   NUMBER(6)
  3          CONSTRAINT LIGNE_COMMANDE_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  4      "QUANTITÉ"            NUMBER(3)
  5          CONSTRAINT LIGNE_COMM_QTT NOT NULL,
  6      ARTICLE_ID          NUMBER(6),
  7  --        CONSTRAINT LIGNECOMM_ARTICLE_FK
  8  --            REFERENCES ARTICLE ( ARTICLE_ID ),
  9      "CATÉGORIE_ID"        NUMBER(6),
 10  --        CONSTRAINT LIGNECOMM_CATÉGORIE_FK
 11  --            REFERENCES CATÉGORIE ( CATÉGORIE_ID ),
 12      COMMANDE_ID         NUMBER(6)
 13  --        CONSTRAINT LIGNECOMM_COMM_FK
 14  --            REFERENCES COMMANDE ( COMMANDE_ID )
 15  );

Table created.
```

Cheers!!